# problem with treeview

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, treeview

I want to configure a treeview so that when all checkboxes of a parent are checked, then the parent checkbox is checked. And when all checkboxes are unchecked, the parent checkbox is unchecked. Does the treeview class have a standard property for that?

Comment: you are using MFC or .Net ? tag your question accordingly with the framework and language you are using.

Comment: .NET i think if i code .NET no purpose to tag language

Comment: Wow, i guess petulance is the new strategy for getting help with something. Let me know how that works out for you, Xaver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is incomplete, it doesn't say what should happen when *some* nodes are checked.  Anyhoo, this kind is code is easy to get going with the AfterCheck event.  For example:

```
private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Node.Parent != null) {
    bool on = true;
    bool off = true;
    foreach (TreeNode node in e.Node.Parent.Nodes) {
      if (node.Checked) off = false;
      else on = false;
    }
    if (off) e.Node.Parent.Checked = false;
    if (on) e.Node.Parent.Checked = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with JavaScript, please check out following link, it may help you to achieve what you want.

[Check/Uncheck Treeview Checkbox](http://nilthakkar.blogspot.com/2009/04/check-uncheck-treeview-checkboxes-with_13.html)

I hope it helps!! :)